# python requests or urllib3 timings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

Is it possible to somehow get the timings when making POST request with python requests or urllib3 library?

I mean, to get how long it took to establish the connection with the server, how long it took to send data and to receive data.

Comment: There are already two similar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159687/measure-website-load-time-with-python-requests
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252542/how-to-measure-server-response-time-for-python-requests-post-request

But I want to calculate separate timings for Connecting, Sending and Receiving, similar to what we can see in Chrome DevTools.

Comment: PyCurl does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803699/7216865